# Error al guardar documento en SD

Tags: android, archivo

Estoy creando una app y quiero guardar un reporte con pdf. Por lo que he visto la libreria itext es una buena eleccion. El problema lo tengo al crear el documento ya que me devuelve un error:

```
    open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

El codigo que utilizo es:

```
            Document document = new Document();

            File prueva = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "prueva.pdf");
            try {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(prueva));
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            document.open();
```

En manifest tengo añadidos los permisos

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Alguna idea? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Según el error, debe ser que estas tratando de guardarlo en la raíz del dispositivo, por eso el `Read-Only` y no has comprobado que efectivamente se guarde en la SD.

Comment: Prueba con `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "prueva.pdf"`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Antes ya havia provado con lo que me has comentado y nada... :( No veo donde puedo tener el error. Gracias por la ayuda! ;)

Comment: Y que es lo que te manda el `Log`?

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/prueva.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: @Ferran que versión estas usando, cual es la dependencia de iTextpdf que agregasta a tu build.gradle ?

Comment: La dependencia de iTextpdf:  'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10' i la version a que te refieres de android el minimo de la app es 15...

Comment: De casualidad estas usando un emulador? @Ferran

Comment: Si. He comprobado que tuviera SD. Hay algun problema con emulador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando el código mencionado en un dispositivo físico no debe existir ningún problema ya que el archivo se crearía en el directorio de almacenamiento externo primario (principal) ya que estas usando el método [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

En cambio si estas usando un emulador este debe tener permisos para escribir en el sistema, si no los tiene puedes iniciar tu emulador de esta forma:

ve al folder `/sdk/emulator` donde contienes tu Android SDK y lo ejecutas de esta forma

```
>emulator -writable-system -avd <Nombre emulador> -no-snapshot-load -qemu
```

por ejemplo si tu `AVD` se llama `Nexus 5X API 25` lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
>emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -no-snapshot-load -qemu
```

Comment: Pues no sé que ha pasado pero una vez he seguido tu consejo ya no puedo arrancar el emulador :( He creado otro y tampoco... Un drama :) Tambien havia provado en mi movil la app y no guardava el documento...

Comment: Si no arranca es que se quedo una instancia del emulador abiera, abre el task manager y termina el emulador.

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Buenas! @Jorgesys yo por mi parte no he marcado el -1 porque no tengo ni la puntuación para hacerlo! ;) He provado todo lo que me dijiste y sigue sin funcionar :( Consegui volver a cargar el emulador con -writable-system pero aunque me indica que es una imagen con permisos de escritura sigue sin funcionar. Aunque tampoco no me funciono al instalarlo en mi mobil. Voy a provar con un ejemplo más básico sin crear un pdf a ver si consigo guardar un archivo sin error. Gracias por la ayuda! ;)

Comment: Buenas! Acabo de volver a executar el proyecto y funciona perfectamente... Así que sin entender muy bien donde estava el error creo que era un problema mio con la configuracion de los emuladores. Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Doy como correcta tu respuesta @Jorgesys porque era por donde creo que iban las cosas. Saludos!